# Wordpress white screen but plugins all deactivated

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I had a problem with a fatal error message appearing after updating Total w3 Cache plugin which caused my site, tarumatu.com, to go down. I reinstalled Wordpress, now i get a white screen. I can log into the admin site, all the content etc is intact, but every page is white. All the plugins are deactivated. What can i do now?

Comment: I've just done it, uploaded a fresh copy of wordpress, using the default theme, same problem - i can access the admin page, all the content is present but still a blank white page. I'm really stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Total w3 Cache , disable it from Total w3 Settings page and then uninstall it again.

Also visit your permalinks page to flush them just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Set WP_DEBUG to true in wp-config.php file and look for any error messages that could point to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your theme is making a call to a function from a plugin. Since you deactivated that plugin, the function no longer exists, causing a fatal error, making your site to display a white screen.

Log into your site's backend using ftp, and delete your theme via ftp. You should now be able to log in to your site as wordpress defaults to one of the default themes.  You must first reactivate the plugin that your theme is making a direct call to, then you can uplaod and activate your theme again